# How will Google Ads API react incase an array becomes empty?

Tags: php, laravel, google-ads-api

I'm working with Google Adwords API in Laravel but I'm pretty new and I need help to understand one thing on a line of code where I got the question I used for this post.

The line is this:

```
$campaign_ids = array_filter(Arr::pluck($campaigns, 'googleId'));
```

Being part of this function:

```
public function reports(CampaignGroup $campaignGroup, string $dateFrom, string $dateTo, int $limit): array
    {
        $campaigns    = [];
        $campaigns    = array_merge($campaigns, $campaignGroup->campaigns->toArray());
        $campaign_ids = array_filter(Arr::pluck($campaigns, 'googleId'));

        $cacheKey = sprintf('keyword_performance_report.%d.%d', $this->account->id, $limit);
        $cacheTtl = DateInterval::createFromDateString($this->cacheTtl);

        $definitionAdapter = new KeywordsPerformanceDefinitionAdapter($campaign_ids);

        return Cache::remember($cacheKey, $cacheTtl, function () use ($definitionAdapter, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $campaign_ids, $limit) {
            $definitionAdapter->applyFilters($campaign_ids, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $limit);
            $definitionAdapter->getSelectorAdapter()->asSummary();

            $response = $this->generate();

            return $response['entries'];
        });
    }
```

I would like to understand what happening if that line will be come an empty array and Google will get that. I was unable to get that and I would like to understand what kind of exception can be throw here and what should I do to avoid such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you pass an empty `$campaign_ids` array, I would expect that statistics for **all** keywords would be returned, as no filtering by campaign is requested.

However, seeing as `KeywordsPerformanceDefinitionAdapter` looks to be some custom code of your application, it might obviously be possible that the actual behavior is different.

Can't you just test the scenario and take note of any error conditions encountered?